# Continuous dependence on initial data

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, numerical-methods

Let $L : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ be a linear operator and ${\| \cdot \|}_{\infty} $ be the maximum norm. Are the following conditions equivalent?

1. For $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $Lx = f$ it holds ${\| x \|}_{\infty} \leq C {\| f \|}_{\infty}$.
2. For $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^d$, with $Lx = f_1, Ly = f_2$ it holds ${\| x - y \|}_{\infty} \leq C {\| f_1 - f_2 \|}_{\infty}$.

Clearly taking $y = 0$ in the second statement yields $f_2 = 0$, which leads to the first statement. Is the converse true? If not, how can the second condition be modified so that the two are equivalent? I have considered the following:

\begin{align}
\| x - y \| = \| x - y + Lx - Lx +Ly - Ly\| &\leq \| Lx - x\| + \| Ly -y\| + \| Lx - Ly \| \\ &=  | Lx - x\| + \| Ly -y\| + \| f_1 - f_2 \|
\end{align}

Comment: Its just linearity, if we start with the first and the assumptions of $2$, then $L(x-y) = f_1 - f_2$, so say $X = x-y$ and $F = f_1 - f_2$ then 1 implies $$\|X\|_\infty \leq C\|F\|_\infty$$ which is the conclusion of 2

Comment: Indeed, so simple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***(1) $\Longrightarrow$ (2):***

Set

$z = x - y; \tag 1$

set

$g = f_1 - f_2; \tag 2$

then

$Lz = L(x - y) = Lx - Ly = f_1 - f_2 = g; \tag 3$

thus, *via* our OP Holden's stipulated item (1),

$\Vert z \Vert_\infty \le C \Vert g \Vert_\infty; \tag 4$

therefore,

$\Vert x - y \Vert_\infty = \Vert z \Vert_\infty \le C \Vert g \Vert_\infty = C\Vert f_1 - f_2 \Vert_\infty, \tag 5$

which is Holden's item (2).

***(2)*** $\Longrightarrow$ ***(1):***

As Holden him/herself points out, taking

$y = 0, \; f_1 = f; \tag 6$

yields

$f_2 = Ly = L0 = 0, \tag 7$

whence

$\Vert x \Vert_\infty = \Vert x - y \Vert_\infty \le C \Vert f_1 - f_2 \Vert_\infty = C \Vert f - 0 \Vert_\infty = C \Vert f \Vert_\infty, \tag 8$

which is Holden's item (1).

Thus the two stipulated hypotheses are, in fact, equivalent.

Comment: You can use `$...$` for small mathematical formulas so that not too much vertical space is used. Also, you don't need to number every line. Indeed in this case it only adds confusion since there are now two things with the name "1" and the name "2".

Comment: @Calvin Khor:  which is why I consistently referred to 'Holden's item (1)" *und so weiter*,  But thanks for the stylistic tips; I'll bear then in mind.  Cheers!

Comment: Well (1) appears in the first 3 lines with different meanings without mention of OP, right? I wasn't confused though, and its not a big deal. You're welcome, have a good day